# How to generate an Oauth1 signature and cookie in python

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, oauth, postman

I am trying to interact with an api, to do that I use Postman, it is working... Then I transform that Postman format to Python requests format, and I receive something like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://apiexample/load/v1/action/uuid"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="aaaaaaaa",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1664816361",oauth_nonce="8zZFKvIdaZE",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="2kNwhbSfe%2Bh5zkE7Qm%2B7BiEt0jo%3D"',
  'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=g-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.env'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I noticed that the values that changes, are this ones:

```
oauth_timestamp="1664816361"
oauth_nonce="8zZFKvIdaZE"
oauth_signature="2kNwhbSfe%2Bh5zkE7Qm%2B7BiEt0jo%3D"
```

To generate the timestamp, I do this:

```
epoch_time = str(time.time())
```

To generate the nonce, this:

```
nonce = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

**But I am having the problems to generate the oauth_signature and the cookie session**... And I feel that thats the only thing that I still need...

Is there a function to generate this signature and cookie? Or is there a way to know how Postman generates both??